# Agregar información de la tabla que se encuentra al lado del formulario

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario con información que viene de MySQL y una tabla.

Ahora requiero agregar información de la tabla que se encuentra al lado del formulario.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "12345678@", "proyecto");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cotizacion WHERE id =" . $id . ";";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<form action="generapdf.php" method="post" >
     <?php  if ($result) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="textDni" class="form-label">DNI : </label>
<input type="text" id="textDni" name="textDni" value="<?= $row["dni"] ?>" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Ingrese Direccion">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">       
                <label for="textNombres" class="form-label">Nombre de Cliente : </label>
                <input type="text" id="textNombres" name="textNombres" value="<?= $row["nombres"] ?> <?= $row["apellidopaterno"] ?>" class="form-control"
                    placeholder=" Ingrese del Cliente">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">           
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="txtDireccion" class="form-label">Direccion : </label>
                <input type="text" id="txtDireccion" name="txtDireccion" value="<?= $row["direccion"] ?>" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Ingrese Direccion">
            </div>         
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="textFecha" class="form-label"> Fecha de Emisión :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textFecha" name="textFecha" value="<?=$row["fechaactual"]?>" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="textDistrito"class="form-label">Distrito :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textDistrito" name="textDistrito" value="<?=$row["distrito"]?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="textFechaatencion"class="form-label"> Fecha de Atencion :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textFechaatencion" name="textFechaatencion" value="<?=$row["fechaatencion"]?> <?=$row["horadeatencion"]?>">
            </div>
        </div> 
//En estos campos quiero agregar información de la tabla que se encuentra al lado, si lo realizo de la forma de siempre desaparece la parte dicha información. 
        <h5 class="card-title text-center"> Datos del Empleado <span>| Generar Cotizacion</span</h5>
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="textNombresemple"class="form-label"> Nombre :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textNombresemple" name="textNombresemple" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="textDniemple"class="form-label"> DNI :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textDniemple" name="textDniemple" value="">  </div> </div>
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="textDistritoemple"class="form-label"> Distrito :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textDistritoemple" name="textDistritoemple" value=" ">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="textCelularemple"class="form-label"> Celular :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textCelularemple" name="textCelularemple" value="">
            </div>
        </div> <?php      }}          ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="textPago" class="form-label">Importe a pagar : </label>
                <input type="text" id="textPago" name="textPago" value="" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Importe a Pagar">
            </div> 
            <br><div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Generar Cotizacion" name="btnCotiza" id="btnCotiza" class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="reset" value="Cancelar" name="btnLimpiar" id="btnLimpiar" class="btn btn-warning">
            </div>
 </form>
 </div>  
            <div class="col-md-8 table-responsive">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Lista de Empleados Libres <span>| Angeles Celestes</span></h5>
                            <table class="table table-striped" >
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Dni</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Nombres</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Apellido<br>P</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Apellido<br>M</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Direccion</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Distrito</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Celular</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Estado<br>Atencion</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                                </tr> <?php  foreach ($rst as $key => $value){ ?>
                                    <tr> <td scope="row"><?=$value->eid?></td>
                                            <td><?=$value->dni?></td>
                                            <td><?=$value->nombres?></td>
                                            <td><?=$value->apellidop?></td>
                                            <td><?=$value->apellidom?></td>
                                            <td><?=$value->direccion?></td> 
                                            <td><?=$value->distrito?></td>
                                            <td><?=$value->celular?></td> 
                                            <td><?=$value->estadoatencion?></td>
                                            <td>    
            <a href="generacotiza.php?eid=<?=$value->eid?>" class = "btn btn-primary">Agregar</a>
            <a href="eliminareserva.php?eid=<?=$value->eid?>" class="btn btn-warning">Eliminar</a>                                       
                                            <td>
                                    </tr> <?php 
                                            }     ?>
  </table>
```

Comment: Lecturas altamente sugeridas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour (aquí obtienes tu primera medalla) + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A tu pregunta le falta explicar qué hace erróneamente tu código y qué se espera que haga. Por favor, explícalo con ejemplos para que todo el mundo pueda entender lo que deseas conseguir.

Comment: Hola, me disculpo es mi primera pregunta que realizo. mi consulta es la siguiente. Mi formulario los primeros 6 input type= text, recogen información de una tabla llamada cotización, hasta ahí todo bien me muestra la información,  ahora lo que requiero es en los siguientes 4 input type=text siguientes, al hacer yo click en el button que se encuentra en la tabla, me agregue información de la tabla  a los 4 input type=text de mi formulario. En una pregunta leí que usando Ajax, podria ser una opcion, ahora estoy revisando ajax, para saber si lo puedo realizar.